# how to get statusBar in iOS 13+?

Tags: statusbar, ios13

[image]

```
UIStatusBarManager *statusBarManager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.windowScene.statusBarManager;
        
if ([statusBarManager respondsToSelector:@selector(createLocalStatusBar)]) {
            UIView *_localStatusBar = [statusBarManager performSelector:@selector(createLocalStatusBar)];
            if ([_localStatusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(statusBar)]) {
                return [_localStatusBar performSelector:@selector(statusBar)];
            }
        }
```

I dont understand why  _localStatusBar is nil, is there anybody knows how to get it, please help me.